# Creating private repository on my pc so that me and my 2 friends can work on a private project?

Tags: android, git, github, repository, private

Me and my 2 friends want to develop an android application(in android studio) and don't want to face any synchronization problems so we thought about uploading it on github, but we want to keep the code private to us. Is there any way that i can install git or any other software on my local computer whose access can only be given to my friends and it helps to synchronize our code.

ps: we have no idea how github works.

Comment: use http://bitbucket.org which offers free private repositories

Comment: You could use Bitbucket, which allows for unlimited private repos with up to five users for free, https://bitbucket.org/ . Alternately, to host your own private repo, all you need is a system with a functioning SSH server, and you can use Git across SSH to access your remote/private repo.

Comment: Try the Git for Windows (formerly mysysgit) to setup a local Git repo with SSH keys.  https://git-for-windows.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a paid github account you can make private repositories where only specified members have access.

P.S. You might want to learn how to use github before deciding you want to use github ;-)